# Cross platform Files APIs - Open and list folders

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, asp.net-web-api, mozilla

I'm going to start this mozilla student project: https://github.com/Mozilla-Student-Projects/Projects-Tracker/issues/54 
I'm a little confused about the WebAPIs, because as far as I know, it's not possible to manage files with JS. 
Someone can point me the right direction to research and test??

I enabled the Firefox DeviceStorage, but I'm not able to getDeviceStorage, the status keeps on 'pending'.

Thx

Comment: Possibly a bit broad for SO? I have given a broad answer below, but maybe you could help us by showing what you've done so far, and describing precisely where you are stuck.

Comment: I just don't know how to start it. I know how to code for Firefox OS, but in this task, I need to write a web app that runs on on web browsers (Firefox/Chrome at least) on Windows/Mac/Linux

Comment: It's possible to access files using all this browsers and systems?

Comment: Yep, the File API is pretty well supported now. The link  give below shows its compatibility, if you scroll to the bottom. Here's a fiddle showing it working with an MP3 - http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/s4P2v/ You could use that info to write an audto tag - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video - which would then let you play the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working on an MDN summer project, you should start here!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File

The summer school thread that you've linked to is looking for a browser app, so I think you'd use the File API to browse for MP3s - here's a fiddle showing it working with an MP3 -

http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/s4P2v/

I've patched this fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/s4P2v/129/

with autoplay="true" so that it actually plays the MP3.

```
html...
<audio id="audio" autoplay="true"></audio>

js....
$("#audio").prop("src", objectUrl);
```

Using the File API, you could use the info to write multiple audio tags - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video - one per MP3 file.

The audio tags would would then let you play the files... and you have the beginnings of an MP3 player.

Comment: Nice! Now, one last question, it's possible, instead of opening the file with the input, request access to the file system and list all musics files? It's possible with DeviceStorage on FOS, but DeviceStorage is not working on the desktop...

Comment: I think you'll need to  clarify that with your Moz summer school folks. If you want it truly browser-only, the user will have to browse for, or drag-drop, the MP3s. If you want silent access to the filesystem, then you'll need to be a privileged (packaged) app and use DeviceStorage API or something else Gaia or Firefox OS gives you, but then you're no longer platform-independent.

Comment: I've re-read the summer school thread. I think he's saying you should build against DeviceStorage, on the assumption that will become the accepted standard for packaged browser apps in future, and that this product will never work as an unpackaged JS webapp. So you can pretty much ignore this answer, because you're question becomes, 'how can I get DeviceSotrage working on Firefox Desktop?'.

Answer (score 1):

You can deal with files but Gaia is for Firefox OS so you have access to privelaged stuff. See the section tagged [firefox-os](/questions/tagged/firefox-os) I'm not sure how to do it, but people in Gaia and Firefox OS help areas can help out.

You can find help for this on irc on the gaia channel, but you have to send a message and wait like 24 hours people arent so active on the irc channels. http://client01.chat.mibbit.com/?server=irc.mozilla.org%3A%2B6697&channel=%23gaia

firefox os and gaia help can also be found in #b2g channel: https://client00.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%23b2g